# Dataframe unstack performance - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to unstack a data-frame. It is working fine, but the problem is that I am working with a huge data-set in CSV file (~ 1 billion).
Here is the sample data-set.

```
236539~!#48512569874~!#Name~!#Danny
236539~!#48512569874~!#Class~!#12
236539~!#48512569874~!#Building~!#X4
236539~!#48512569875~!#Name~!#John
236539~!#48512569875~!#Class~!#10
236539~!#48512569875~!#Shelf~!#Yes
236539~!#48512569875~!#Desk_ID~!#2018_5D
236539~!#48512569876~!#Name~!#Xian
236539~!#48512569876~!#Desk_ID~!#2018_3D
236539~!#48512569876~!#Country~!#CHN
```

I am reading the above huge data set by using `chunksize` in `read_csv()` method, then concatenating the data-set into a complete data-frame.

While unstacking it is taking a lot of time (although reading the data from csv also was taking time but applying `chunksize` and `pd.concat` improves the performance)
Below is the code I have used for unstacking:

```
df = pd.read_csv('panda1.csv', delimiter='~!#', engine='python',header=None, keep_default_na=False, na_values=[''])
df.columns = ['School_Id', 'Student_Id', 'Attribute_Name', 'Attribute_Value']
var_list = ['Name','Class','Building','Shelf','Desk_ID','Country']
df = df.set_index(['School_Id', 'Student_Id', 'Attribute_Name'])['Attribute_Value'].unstack(fill_value='').fillna('')[var_list].reset_index()
```

After unstacking it is coming exactly what i want.

```
School_Id   Student_Id  Name    Class   Building    Shelf   Desk_ID Country
236539      48512569874 Danny   12      X4           ''      ''       ''
236539      48512569875 John    10                   Yes    2018_5D   ''
236539      48512569876 Xian    ''      ''           ''     2018_3D   CHN
```

But when I am trying to create a data-frame with large data set (~1 Billion) and unstacking it either it is taking long time to process or memory error,
so is there any option to do the unstacking operation in chunk to get the desired result.

Comment: If you need to do it once, I think you can split your file before converting and convert each part separately. Then stack them and write at file. Or if you need to do this regularly, you should think about something like map - reduce. And as far as I know you should use np.concatenate instead pd.concat, because it will be faster and take less memory.

Comment: @AnnaIliukovich-Strakovskaia I need to do this regularly. As per your suggestion could you provide some details or code snippet regarding map -reduce as I have not used it before.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know good tutorials for that. I wanted to say that you should use something for paralleling your code. I'm not good in it. But I can recommend look at job lib for parallel your code : http://queirozf.com/entries/parallel-for-loops-in-python-examples-with-joblib or at map-reduce (but I think it's more difficult) - http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/