# pandas stack and unstack performance reduces after dataframe compression and is much worse than R's data.table

Tags: python, r, pandas, data.table

This question is about boosting Pandas' performance during stacking and unstacking operation.

The issue is that I have a large dataframe (~2GB). I followed [this blog](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/pandas-big-data/) to compress it to ~150MB successfully. However, my stacking and unstacking operation take infinite amount of time such that I have to kill the kernel and restart everything.

I have also used R's `data.table` package, and it just flies, meaning it completes the operation in <1 second.

I researched this on SO. It seems that some people have pointed to `map-reduce` on [Dataframe unstack performance - pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51979636/dataframe-unstack-performance-pandas) thread, but I am not sure about it for two reasons:

1. `stack` and `unstack` on uncompressed runs fine in `pandas`, but I can't do this on my original dataset because of memory problems.
2. R's `data.table` easily (<1 second) converts from long to wide format.

I managed to cut a small feed (5MB) for representation purpose for SO. The feed has been uploaded to http://www.filedropper.com/ddataredact. This file should be able to reproduce the problem.

Here's my `pandas` code:

```
import pandas as pd

#Added code to generate test data
data = {'ANDroid_Margin':{'type':'float','len':13347},
        'Name':{'type':'cat','len':71869},
        'Geo1':{'type':'cat','len':4},
        'Geo2':{'type':'cat','len':31},
        'Model':{'type':'cat','len':2}}

ddata_i = pd.DataFrame()
len_data =114348
#categorical
for colk,colv in data.items():
    print("Processing column:",colk)
    #Is the data type numeric?
    if data[colk]['type']=='cat':
        chars = string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase
        replacement_value = [
            "".join(
                [random.choice(chars) for i in range(5)]
            ) for j in range(data[colk]['len'])]

    else:
        replacement_value = np.random.uniform(
            low=0.0, high=20.0, size=(data[colk]['len'],))
    ddata_i[colk] = np.random.choice(
        replacement_value,size=len_data,replace = True)

#Unstack and Stack now. This will show the result quickly
ddata_i.groupby(["Name","Geo1","Geo2","Model"]).\
    sum().\
    unstack().\
    stack(dropna=False).\
    reset_index()

#Compress our data
ddata = ddata_i.copy()

df_obj = ddata.select_dtypes(include=['object']).copy()
for col in df_obj:
    df_obj.loc[:, col] = df_obj[col].astype('category')
ddata[df_obj.columns] = df_obj

df_obj = ddata.select_dtypes(include=['float']).copy()
for col in df_obj:
    df_obj.loc[:, col] = df_obj[col].astype('float')
ddata[df_obj.columns] = df_obj

#Let's quickly check whether compressed file is same as original file
assert ddata.shape==ddata_i.shape, "Output seems wrong"
assert ddata_i.ANDroid_Margin.sum()==ddata.ANDroid_Margin.sum(),"Sum isn't right"
for col in ["ANDroid_Margin","Name","Geo1","Geo2"]:
    assert sorted(list(ddata_i[col].unique()))==sorted(list(ddata[col].unique()))

#This will run forever
ddata.groupby(["Name","Geo1","Geo2","Model"]).\
    sum().\
    unstack().\
    stack(dropna=False).\
    reset_index()
```

You will note that stacking and unstacking operation on `ddata_i` will run quickly, but not on compressed `ddata`. Why is this?

Also, I noticed that if I compress either `object` or `float`, then `stack()` and `unstack()` will run quickly. It's only when I do both, the problem persists.

Can someone please help me understand what I am missing? How can I fix the problem with `pandas` above ? I feel that with such big performance issues, how can I write production-ready code in `pandas`? I'd appreciate your thoughts.

---

Finally, here's R's `data.table` code. I have to say that `data.table` is not only fast, but I don't have to go through compressing and decompressing.

```
df <- data.table::fread("ddata_redact.csv",
                        stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                        data.table = TRUE, 
                        header = TRUE)

df1=data.table::dcast(df, Name + Geo1 + Geo2 ~ Model, 
                      value.var = "ANDroid_Margin",
                      fun.aggregate = sum)
```

Can someone please help me understand what I am missing? How can I fix the problem with `pandas` above ? I feel that with such big performance issues, how can I write production-ready code in `pandas`? I'd appreciate your thoughts.

---

Python's sys info:

```
sys.version_info
> sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=7, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

pandas version

```
pd.__version__
> '0.23.4'
```

data.table

```
1.11.8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the answer. The issue is that we need to add `observed = True` to prevent `pandas` from computing cartesian product.

After compression, I had to run this...

```
ddata.groupby(["Name","Geo1","Geo2","Model",observed = True]).\
    sum().\
    unstack().\
    stack(dropna=False).\
    reset_index()
```